# Converting from C# to Powershell syntax 

Tags: powershell

In C# I can use the method `Console.Error.WriteLine`. This doesn't work in Powershell, instead I must write

```
[Console]::Error.WriteLine
```

Why square brackets, why the double colons?

ps. To be clear, I'm not interested in logging, I want to understand the syntax about types and objects and methods

Comment: That's always the challenge with funny syntax features. You can't Google it (easily)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brackets = access to a type

double colons = access to a static member of a type : [MyType] return a Type instance

ex:

> c:> [System.Int32]
>
> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>
> -------- -------- ----                                     --------
>
> True     True     Int32     System.ValueType

using the dot notation would only give you access to instance members of the Type instance (reflection related methods for most)...

```
c:\> [System.Int32].Parse("3")

Method call failed because [System.Runtype] does not have any "Parse" member

c:\> [System.Int32].AssemblyQualifiedName

System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

so :: is the way to access static members of a Class

```
c:\> [System.Int32]::Parse("3")
3
```

Answer (score 5):

The square brackets `[]` are Powershell's way of denoting a type. The double colons `::` represent a static member or method of that type, where the normal period `.` represents an instance member or method.

Note that these were influenced by other .NET languages - C# uses the `.` for all member access, and C++ uses the `::` for namespaces, subclasses, and static calls.

Answer (score 0):

Watch it here - 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jpswk-4ykcc